# Erro ao adicionar chave estrangeira a tabela

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "tela_inicial_id" referenced in
>   foreign key constraint does not exist   ERROR: column
>   "tela_inicial_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist 
>   ERROR: column "tela_inicial_id" referenced in foreign key constraint
>   does not exist

Script tabela tela_inicial:

```
-- criar TelaInicial 
create table tela_inicial (
    id int8 not null,
    tela_inicial_id int8 not null,
    nome_menu varchar(255),
    menu_url varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);
create sequence tela_inicial_id_seq;

-- chave estrangeira para usuario e tela inicial
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tela_inicial_id FOREIGN KEY (tela_inicial_id) REFERENCES tela_inicial (id);
```

Comment: Na sua tabela 'usuario' existe essa coluna 'tela_inicial_id'? Se não, este é o problema que está sendo logado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa tarde!

Você definiu como chave primária o campo id. e não o campo tela_inicial_id. vc pode mudar na tabela a chave primária para ser o tela_inicial_id ou mudar no comando alter table.

No exemplo baixo mudei no alter table:

```
-- criar TelaInicial 
create table tela_inicial (
    id int8 not null,
    tela_inicial_id int8 not null,
    nome_menu varchar(255),
    menu_url varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);
create sequence tela_inicial_id_seq;

-- chave estrangeira para usuario e tela inicial
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tela_inicial (id);
```